# Web2py.exe Immediately Closes

Tags: python, web2py

Following a tutorial, I have downloaded the Web2py Windows binaries.  When I open web2py.exe, I get a quick command prompt screen.  It immediately closes.  I have uninstalled previous versions of Python, with no change.  I also followed a recommendation from another post to create a .bat file to see the error.  When I run it, I get the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       file "<string>", line 6, in <module>
       file "__main__.py", line 128, in <module>
       file "__main_web2py__.py", line 33, in <module>
    TypeError:  start() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the .exe, but note the .exe comes with its own Python interpreter, so it doesn't interact at all with your system installed Python. If you do have Python installed, you're probably better off just using the source version of web2py anyway (the .exe is just for easy portability to systems without Python installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing pythone 32 bit version and web2py source version.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work.  I had to install python 2.7 and use the web2py source version.  I had tried Python 3.8 with the source version, but it would not work.  Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction.